# why does python's panda return differce found when compare two csv files and the cell is empty?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[image](1) I am using Python's pandas to compare two csv files. In the both files have exact same data set and should return something like the statement "two files are identical". However, there is one column with header of "Error" and the column are empty because there is no recorded value of error.

(2) when I do a file compare, the script pick up the "error" column as true ( or difference found)

(3) my code is below

(4) Can someone help? how can I avoid a cell if it is empty? Actually I have another set of data [image]and in those two files there are column with value of "None" and it has the same behavior. ( both file : file a and file b at the same locations with value of "None" and compare result said there is difference after compare.)

my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np  # Import numpy for NaN values

# List of file paths
file_paths = ['test_file_1.csv', 'test_file_2.csv']

# Create a list to store DataFrames
dataframes = []

# Load all CSV files into DataFrames
for file_path in file_paths:
    df = pd.read_csv(file_path)
    dataframes.append(df)

# Initialize a dictionary to store differences
differences = {}

# Compare each pair of DataFrames
for i in range(len(dataframes)):
    for j in range(i + 1, len(dataframes)):
        df1 = dataframes[i]
        df2 = dataframes[j]

        # Check if either DataFrame is None or has errors
        if df1 is None or df2 is None:
            continue

        # Fill empty cells with NaN
        df1 = df1.fillna(np.nan)
        df2 = df2.fillna(np.nan)

        # Compare the DataFrames cell by cell
        comparison_df = df1 != df2  # Use != to create a boolean DataFrame where differences are True
        print("BreakPoint")
        # Find the row and column indices where differences occur
        diff_locations = comparison_df.stack().reset_index()
        diff_locations.columns = ['Row', 'Column', 'Different']

        # Filter rows where differences are True
        diff_locations = diff_locations[diff_locations['Different']]

        # Store differences in the dictionary
        key = f'({file_paths[i]}) vs ({file_paths[j]})'
        differences[key] = diff_locations
        print("break point")

# Output the differences
for key, diff_locations in differences.items():
    if diff_locations.empty:
        print(f"{key}: The two CSV files are identical.")
    else:
        print(f"{key}: The two CSV files have differences at the following locations:")
        print(diff_locations)
```

Comment: Show us the csv files, and show us the full output from the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NaNs never compare equal to themselves.  Your `df1.fillna(np.nan)` is pointless to begin with -- the columns already had NaN.  I suggest you use:

```
    df1 = df1.fillna('')
    df2 = df2.fillna('')
```

or, better:

```
    df1.fillna('', inplace=True)
    df2.fillna('', inplace=True)
```

Comment: Thanks Tim, using df1.fillna('') helps. I got the correct output.